# Benefits of using a hosted search service over building your own

Tags: node.js, performance, postgresql, search, multilingual

I'm building a B2B Node app which has heavily related data models. We currently have our own search queries, but as we scale some of the queries appear to be becoming sluggish.

We will need to support multilingual search as well as content-based searches (searching matching content within related data).

The queries are growing more and more complicated (each has multiple joins on joins on joins) and I'm now considering a hosted search tool such as [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

Given my concerns below, why should I use a hosted cloud search service rather than continue building my own queries?

- Data privacy is important
- Data is hosted in our own postgres DB - integrations with that are important (e.g.: will I now need to manually maintain our DB data and data in Algolia?)
- Speed will be important, but not so much now
- Must be able to do content-based searches across multiple languages
- We are a tiny team of devs now, so dev resource time is vital

What other things should I be concerned about that can help make a decision in search capabilities?

---

Regarding maintenance of both DB and Cloud data, it seems it's as simple as getting all data, caching it, and storing it in the cloud:

```
var index = Algolia.initIndex('contacts');
var contactsJSON = require('./contacts.json');

index.addObjects(contactsJSON, function(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Search services like Algolia or self-hosted Elasticsearch/solr operate as full text search, not relational db queries.

But it sounds like the bottleneck is the continual rejoining.  Which if you can make your relational data act like a full text document db then that could be a more efficient type of index (pre-joined sort of).

You might also look into views, or a data warehouse (maybe star schema).

But if you are going the search route maybe investigate hosting your own elasticsearch.

You could specify database, schema, sql, index, query details if you want more help.

Comment: Jason, so if our data lives as related models in a DB and our search functionality is to use FTS features within large queries (`to_tsvector(text) @@ to_tsquery('hi & there')`), would it make sense to use a search service? Would I need to reconfigure our database layer to use something like `Algolia`? I'm not sure what you mean by `"operate as full text search, not relational db queries."`... And `"Which if you can make your relational data act like a full text document db"` - We're using Postgresql to do FTS on individual fields in a set of records.

Comment: Like I said I would try to set up solr or elasticsearch, its not that hard and you can control it. Whether you use elasticsearch or Algolia/whatever it will be a separate index/document store that you will need to copy data into.  It won't hit your relational tables.  Should be faster than tsvector etc.

Comment: `"But if you are going the search route maybe investigate hosting your own elasticsearch."` - I'm not sure I understand this. I am currently able to search by using `tsvector`

Answer (score 0):

Full Disclosure: I founded a company called SearchStax on the premise that companies and developers should not spend time setting up, managing, scaling or building tools for the search infrastructure (ops) - they are better off investing time of their employees into building value for the company, whether that be features, capabilities, product or customers.

Open Source Search solutions based on top of Lucene (Apache Solr / Elasticsearch) have what you need now and what you might need in near future from a capability perspective from a search engine. Find a mature service provider / AS-A-Service company that has specialization in open source search and let them deal with all. It may look small effort right now, though it's probably not worth time and effort of your devs to spend time on the operations of that.

For your concerns mentioned above:

**Data privacy is important**

Your concern around Privacy and Security are addressable. There are multiple ways  you can secure your Solr environment and the right MSP or a Managed Solution provider should be able to address those.

a. Security at the **transport layer** can be addressed by SSL certificates. All the data going over the wire is encrypted. 
b. IP Filtering and User Based Authentication should address **who has access** to what. Solr-as-a-Service offering by Measured Search supports both.
c. **Security at rest** can be addressed in multiple ways - OS level / File encryption, but you can even go further by ensuring not even your services provider has access to that data by using Searchable Encryption technology.

Privacy concerns are all address by Terms & Conditions - I am sure your legal department will address that from a Service Provider's perspective.

**Data is hosted in our own postgres DB - integrations with that are important**

Solr provides ability to import data directly (DIH) through a traditional relational database (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, etc). You can either use that so Solr can pull data periodically or write your own simple script to push data through the Solr APIs.

If you are hosted in the cloud (AWS), a tunnel can be created so only the Solr deployments have the ability to pull data from your servers and your database servers are not exposed to the world, if you choose to go the DIH route.

**Speed will be important, but not so much now**

Solr is built for search speed - I don't think that's where your problems are going to be. Service offering like Measured Search's - you can spin up a cluster in any data center supported by AWS or Azure and make sure your search deployments are closer to your application servers so the latency overhead is minimal.

**Must be able to do content-based searches across multiple languages**

Yes, Solr supports that. More than 30 languages.

**We are a tiny team of devs now, so dev resource time is vital**

I am biased here, but I would not have my developers spend much time on operations and let them focus on what they do best - build great product capabilities to push the limits and deliver business value.

If you are interested in doing a comparison and ROI of doing it yourself vs using a solr-as-a-service like offered by SearchStax, check this paper out - https://www.searchstax.com/white-papers/why-measured-search-is-better-than-diy-solr-infrastructure/